# Being a middle man in paypal mobile transactions

Tags: ios, paypal, payment-processing

Using the paypal iOS sdk, is possible to:

1-take a payment from one user for X dollars plus a fee of Y
2-deposit X+Y into your paypal account
3-make a payment of X to another user

I'm looking for an approach that will do this and for all intents and purposes, the users on both ends will only see the regular paypal api payment workflow.

I've looked at the documentation and steps 1 and 2 seem pretty straightforward, I'm just confused about how to do step 3 *automatically* without user intervention. My first guess would be to use the "send money" functionality of the API to send money from my account to that second user but I believe that would eliminate the chance of reversing the whole transaction (in case a refund is needed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is called Chained Payments (more info on https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro) but iOS SDK currently does not have support for them. But even with chained payments you can't automatically reverse both legs of the transaction.

Comment: I see, thanks for the link. Do you happen to know how people handle refunds in chained payments?

Comment: You could get the secondary receiver give you a 3rd party permission to do refunds on their behalf. That way you would first refund the secondary payment and then do a refund from your account.